# Timeout waiting to lock journal cache with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, caching, timeout

```
 > Could not create service of type FileAccessTimeJournal using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal().
                           > Timeout waiting to lock journal cache (/Users/mark/.gradle/caches/journal-1). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
                             Owner PID: 7366
                             Our PID: 7609
                             Owner Operation: 
                             Our operation: 
                             Lock file: /Users/mark/.gradle/caches/journal-1/journal-1.lock
```

I have two repos on my mac that I am trying to run at the same time with gradle bootRun. I can run one of them fine, but when I run the other I get this message. I have never seen this before when running two repos with gradle. I have tried using gradle --stop, deleting my caches file in gradle, removing "*.lock" file, and restarting the daemons. Nothing works.

What is happening?

Answer (score 5):

You can kill the gradle proccess stucked:

`sudo kill -9 <Owner PID>`

In your case:
`sudo kill -9 7366`

Answer (score 4):

close your android studio and just delete

```
/Users/mark/.gradle/caches/journal-1/journal-1.lock
```

this file, and test again

Comment: This wasn't enough for me. I had to remove all lock files in the `.gradle` folder, running
`find ~/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" -delete`